# SQL Server trigger can't insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I beginning to learn how to write trigger with this basic database.

I'm also making my very 1st database.

Schema

**Team**:

```
TeamID int PK (TeamID int IDENTITY(0,1) CONSTRAINT TeamID_PK PRIMARY KEY)
TeamName nvarchar(100)
```

**History**:

```
HistoryID int PK (HistoryID int IDENTITY(0,1) CONSTRAINT HistoryID_PK PRIMARY KEY)
TeamID int FK REF Team(TeamID)
WinCount int
LoseCount int
```

My trigger: when a new team is inserted, it should insert a new history row with that team id

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_Player
ON Team
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO History (TeamID, WinCount, LoseCount)
        SELECT DISTINCT i.TeamID 
        FROM Inserted i
        LEFT JOIN History h ON h.TeamID = i.TeamID 
                            AND h.WinCount = 0 AND h.LoseCount = 0
END
```

Executed it returns

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Please help thank. I'm using SQL Server

Comment: error has nothnig to do with trigger.you have 3 column for insert,but you are selecting only 2 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error text is the best guide, it is so clear ..

You try inserting one value from `i.TeamID` into three columns `(TeamID,WinCount,LoseCount)`

consider these `WinCount` and `LoseCount` while inserting.

---

**Note**: I Think the structure of `History` table need to revisit, you should select `WinCount` and `LoseCount` as Expressions not as actual columns.

Comment: I understood now. Thanks sir.

Comment: @KitsuneHifu Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you specify insert columns,  you say which columns you will be filling. But in your case,  right after  insert you select only one column (team id).

You either have to modify the insert to contain only one column,  or select,  to retrieve 3 fields as in insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you mention the columns where values have to be inserted(Using INSERT-SELECT).

The SELECT Statement has to contain the same number of columns that have been specified to be inserted. Also, ensure they are of the same data type.(You might face some issues otherwise)